# Inserting MatchCollection into datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I have a datagridview that has 2 columns and a MatchCollection that I will be using to fill the datagrid. How can i insert into the datagrid for the first column the first match in matchcollection then for the second column the second value of matchcollection. It will then create a new row and start again.

No data is bound to this gridview and I need to ensure that the matchCollection that is being inserted into the datagrid does not overwrite anything else in the table. How can i do this?

This is done in forms application not asp.net

```
 while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = sr.ReadLine();
                        line = line.Trim();
                        if (line.StartsWith("addTestingPageContentText"))
                        {
                            string temp;
                            string pattern = "\"([^\"]+)\"";
                            Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
                            MatchCollection regs = r.Matches(line);

                            foreach (Match reg in regs)
                            {

                                temp = reg.ToString();
                                temp = temp.Replace("\"", "");

                               int rowCount = contentTable_grd.Rows.Count - 1;


                        if (contentTable_grd.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Value == null)
                            contentTable_grd.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Value = temp;
                        else
                            contentTable_grd.Rows[rowCount].Cells[1].Value = temp;


                        contentTable_grd.Rows.Add();

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.StartsWith("addTestingPageContentText"))
                {
                    string temp;
                    string pattern = "\"([^\"]+)\"";
                    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
                    MatchCollection regs = r.Matches(line);


                    object[] array1 = new object[2];                    



                    foreach (Match reg in regs)
                    {

                        temp = reg.ToString();
                        temp = temp.Replace("\"", "");

                        if (array1[0] == null)
                            array1[0] = temp;
                        else
                            array1[1] = temp;
                    }

                    if (regs.Count > 0)
                        contentTable_grd.Rows.Add(array1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom gridview column and inherit from DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

[Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)